# how to shut off display by shortcut key even if mouse is still moving and clicking

Tags: windows-8.1, display, power-management, imac

It looks like a stupid question but I really need this function.

First I'm running windows on iMac so I don't have a physical  screen power button.

Second the **mouse is being continuously operated by scripting tools** to do some auto testing works. normal screen offs will be wake up by the scripting tools's mouse actions.even setting the mouse does not wake the device in device manager won't help.

And I want to save some power when I'm leaving.

OS is windows 8.1.

Comment: Maybe check out this link: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-shutdown-or-sleep-windows-10-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/#:~:text=Method%202%3A%20Alt%20%2B%20F4%20Sleep%20Mode%20Shortcut&text=However%2C%20if%20you%20don't,for%20sleep%20in%20Windows%2010.&text=To%20make%20sure%20you%20don,Shut%20Down%20Windows%20dialog%20box.

Comment: You can also turn way down your screen brightness in settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to shut down the screen, but since you are using mouse input in the background your mileage may vary with some of the following methods and you may need to look into this [mouse fix for screen activation](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/stop-mouse-from-waking-windows-up-from-sleep-mode/)

## **METHOD 1**

You could try creating a batch file with the following script and use [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to activate it:

```
echo off
C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe -Change -monitor-timeout-dc 1
C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe -Change -monitor-timeout-ac 1
START /MIN /WAIT C:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr -s
C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe -Change -monitor-timeout-dc m1
C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe -Change -monitor-timeout-ac m2
```

replace m1 and m2 with the idle time for switching off your display defined in control panel.

Control Panel > Power Options > whichever "Active" Power Plan > Change Plan Settings > Turn off the display setting (minutes).
For example in my laptop m1 = 10 and m2 = 30.

Now create a shortcut to this batch file and optionally assign a Hotkey and an Icon.

*Explanation of the script:*

The first two commands sets the Display Off idle time for the minimum possible setting of 1 Minute for both AC and DC (Battery) power. The third command put the system in Blank Screen Saver mode "instantly", and /WAIT for the screen saver application to terminate. After 1 minute of idle time the Monitor will switch off power completely.
Once the screen saver /WAIT is terminated by the wakeup event of a mouse movement or keystroke, the last two lines of code will revert the Display idle time-out to the original defined settings in Control Panel. This to ensure that after wake-up, the display does not turn-off every 1 minute of idle time out.

## METHOD 2

THere is a program for Windows called [Display Power Off Utility](https://www.maketecheasier.com/turn-off-windows-screen/) is a free utility program designed to help you switch off your Windows PC screen. It is easy to use and doesn’t have any Graphical User Interface. You run it like you run a BAT file

## METHOD 3

You could try using [Blacktop Tool](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Launchers-Shutdown-Tools/BlackTop.shtml) to Turn Off Windows PC Screen. The black top tool is like the Windows BAT file, except that it allows you to use a keyboard shortcut to run it instead of clicking on it. The shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+

Sources:

[How to turn off my monitor](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-turn-off-the-monitor-ie-put-it-to-sleep/0ea689fd-bc46-4329-8f2c-bf9967d18114?auth=1)

[7 Ways to Quickly Turn Your Windows Screen Off](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-turn-off-the-monitor-ie-put-it-to-sleep/0ea689fd-bc46-4329-8f2c-bf9967d18114?auth=1)

Comment: all the methods will be wake up immediately since the mouse is always moving and clicking in foreground.

Comment: look into this - https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/stop-mouse-from-waking-windows-up-from-sleep-mode/

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any program to be able to turn off the screen without turning it on when moving the mouse or pressing a key on the keyboard. I need the screen to stay off.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155246)